# How to use generalised linear mixed model with compositional (proportions that add up to 1) predictors?

Tags: r, mixed-model

The study analyses the eye gaze of users and sees whether eye gaze can be used to predict the memorability of the scenario. My goal is to look at the interaction between time and visual target (screen, robot, and others) and see if the user's gaze distribution at an earlier stage (specifically, the first 25 seconds out of the 120 seconds) is more indicative of memorability than the user's gaze distribution at later stages.
The following variables are relevant to the study:

1. **Memorized**: Binary Response Variable with 0 meaning not memorized and one meaning memorized
2. **Level**: It is a categorical variable from 0 -> 23. And this basically means the time interval. 0 means the first 5 secs, and 23 means the 23rd 5secs interval (so, 115s-120s interval)
3. **Robot**: This is the proportion of time when the user looked at the robot
4. **Screen**: This is the proportion of time when the user looked at the screen
5. **Other**: This is the proportion of time when the user looked at a target that is not robot or the screen.
6. **Visual**: This is another categorical variable that identifies the scenario that the user was looking at. A single scenario with multiple participants was used, so I used this as a random effect.

Note that robot + screen + other always adds up to 1. Each data point is a 5-second interval (represented by a number from 0 to 23) with the associated gaze distribution and memorability (response).

I have the following generalized linear mixed model (generalized because the response variable is binary):

```
memorized ~ 1 + level + robot + screen + level:screen + level:robot + (1 | visual)
```

The reason I omitted one of the targets (other) is because they are dependent on the robot and screen.

**My question is, can I use proportions as a predictor variable?** If you have any questions about the context, please feel free to ask.

Another question I have is, if I have 24 time steps (the 5 secs time intervals), what is the best way to model to check whether initial time steps have a better effect at indicating memorability than the later time steps? I am not sure if the current modelling can be used to get that information.

Comment: How many visual categories? If less than 5, a random intercept might be a strech. Was each user measured on multiple occasions? I think the answer is yes. If so, then you should likely have a random intercept for user. `(1|user)`

Comment: @ErikRuzek There are more than five visual categories. Each user was measured on multiple occasions with different visuals (or scenarios). However, each user did not participate in all the visual categories/scenarios. So do I use both user and visual as random effects then?

Comment: Also, is this the best way to represent time intervals, given my goal? Or is there a better way to do that? My initial data was basically frames. We had a 30fps eye gaze detector that collected 3600 frames per scenario/user combination. This is the raw data. I then processed it into 5 secs intervals with eye gaze distribution.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yes, you can model both user and visual as random intercepts. In terms of the time intervals, with 25 levels, one might be inclined to include that as a random intercept, but that is based on an assumption of normality for the intercepts. I'm not sure that makes sense. If it doesn't then you can include interval as a factor in the fixed (non-varying) part of the model. You can use `emmeans` to test the hypothesis about early time intervals vs. later time intervals.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @ErikRuzek! The only effect I want to see of time is whether gaze patterns at earlier (t <= 35s) are better than later gaze patterns. Thanks for suggesting the use of `emmeans`. However, for that, I would need a good model. My question is, does it make sense to have the time variable (I changed it to a binary variable which has 1 if t <= 35s and 0 otherwise) as a fixed effect? I would say no because I am not interested in seeing the direct effect of time. Does the interaction of the time variable with the robot, screen, or other make sense?